# How to make make a change to code in VS in a batch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

Any ideas on how to make a change to some html code in visual studio in a batch replace in many files at once when "find and replace" won't suffice? For example, changing the menu items (nav items) when there are 50+ nav items in 50+ web pages, which won't fit in a normal "find and replace" command in Visual Studio.

Ex: adding a menu item (nav item) in the `<ul>` list of menu items in 50+ pages, rather than manually changing each html page to reflect the updated navigation menu.

Also, I know razor is probably a better option in the future, but right now implementing it is not on the list of to-do items.

Comment: you will be spending a lot more time writing this code then actually just opening each file and changing it, then when you are tired of that, you might move to a better technology in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my [Sync Block Edit](https://vlasovstudio.com/sync-block-edit/) extension to update duplicate blocks of text in multiple files.